# difference between static route and default-information originate

Tags: networking

Can anybody tell me difference between static routing and default-information originate.

both do the same thing as both route the unknown traffic to the specific destination.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

With static routes you can specify static next hop for some specific subnet. You may use 0.0.0.0/0 to act as a catch-all network which will in effect route all networks to the specified next hop unless you have more specific route available. Floating static routes may come and go from the routing table depending on the situation but individual routes are still static.

In cisco OSPF default-information originate, on the other hand, allows your routing process to (re-)distribute default route to other peers participating in the said routing protocol.